# Putting Contracts for Constructor Arguments

Tags: c#, code-contracts, contracts

Assume we have an interface as follows with the contract class

```
[ContractClassFor(typeof(Custom))]
public abstract class CustomContract : Custom
{
    public string GetPerson(int i)
    {
        Contract.Requires(i > 0);
        Contract.Ensures(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Contract.Result<string>()));
        return default(string);
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[ContractClass(typeof(CustomContract))]
    public interface Custom
    {
        string GetPerson(int i);
        string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Implementation is like

```
    public class CustomProcessor: Custom
    {
         public CustomProcessor(ISomeinterface obj, string logname)
         {
              if(null == obj) throw new ArgumentNullException(...);
               ...
         }
         public GetPerson(int I)
         {
             ...
         } 
    }
```

Does it make sense to replace the `throw new ArgumentNullException` in constructor with `Contract.Requires(obj != null).`

Contracts are supposed to be defined by an interface and since constructor is a part of implementation and not an interface I am leaned towards the current approach.
Is that a good practice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the most out of code contracts, yes, it makes sense to replace the `ArgumentNullException` throws with `Contract.Requires`.

This is perfectly all right given the fact that you're using an interface and a contract class. There is simply no other place to validate the constructor parameters other than in the constructor itself.

If you use the `ArgumentNullException` approach then you'll miss out on code contract's static checking and other goodies.